# Set of 2D points vote for a target points

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, computer-science, ransac

Let's consider following problem: Given a set of 2D points `P = {p1, p2, ..., pn}`, we predict a set of translation vectors (votes) `T = {t1, t2, ..., tn}` to point at same target point B. What is the best way to find B, where T could be noisy?

I like to try `RANSAC` to remove outliers, but not sure what would be fit model then?

I tried:

1. Just taking the mean of `B = {b1, b2, ..., bn}`, where `bi = pi + ti`
2. Trimmed mean, to remove outlier problem of sol. 1. (cons: consider 2D position of the voters might help for a better vote)
3. The point has most number of neighbor. (2 points are called neighbor if their Euclidean distance be smaller than some threshold).
4. Clustering: Find the largest neighborhood where points vote for the same points.

Comment: What do you mean by "vote"? How do you predict your "votes"? Why do you add each "vote" to a corresponding point (`pi + ti`)?

Comment: @coproc, Ok, I edited the question to be more clear, a vote could be a translation vector, where point to a target point B. (e.g. set of points P in a circle, where for each given points pi we predict a translation vector ti, so pi + ti would be center of the circle )

Comment: So actually you have a set of points `{b1, b2, ..., bn}`, where each `bi` is a "measurement result" of a point `b` and you want to guess `b`? (no need to know that your `bi` result from some other points and predictions)

Comment: @coproc, that is not completely true, since by knowing bi is the vote of pi, we might be able to guess a better target points. Clustering might be useful in this case.

Comment: But then we need more information about `pi` and `ti` explaining why clustering the `pi` would be better than clustering the `bi`. You want to take the mean of the `bi` to get `b`, but you want to cluster the `pi`? To get actually what? This is not a well posed problem.